# IndexOutOfBoundsException when converting html to pdf using itext.html2pdf

Tags: java, pdf, itext, itext7

I tried to convert html to pdf using itext.html2pdf converter, the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 17, Size: 17
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:1227)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.get(ArrayList.java:1044)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableBorders.processAllBordersAndEmptyRows(TableBorders.java:139)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.CollapsedTableBorders.updateBordersOnNewPage(CollapsedTableBorders.java:542)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.TableRenderer.layout(TableRenderer.java:309)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.layout(BlockRenderer.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.layout(BlockRenderer.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.LineRenderer.layout(LineRenderer.java:339)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.ParagraphRenderer.layout(ParagraphRenderer.java:209)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.layout(BlockRenderer.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.BlockRenderer.layout(BlockRenderer.java:219)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.renderer.RootRenderer.addChild(RootRenderer.java:134)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.attach.impl.layout.HtmlDocumentRenderer.close(HtmlDocumentRenderer.java:193)
    at com.itextpdf.layout.Document.close(Document.java:135)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:149)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:135)
    at com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(HtmlConverter.java:110)
```

I am using iTextpdf.html2pdf version 2.0.2.

Is there any workaround or am I just doing something wrong?

Using below code to convert"

```
RestTemplate rTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpMessageConverter<String> sMessageConverter = new StringHttpMessageConverter(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> httpMessageConverter = Lists.newArrayList();
httpMessageConverter.add(sMessageConverter);
rTemplate.setMessageConverters(httpMessageConverter);
String d = rTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);
org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parse(d, "utf-8");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(document.html(), outputArray);
return outputArray.toByteArray();
```

Comment: Can you share an example html for which that happens?

Comment: Seems like it would be that the document.html() is producing something that HtmlConvter does not like.  Maybe look at the produced html, is something wonky with it - looks like the PDFRender is choking on table html to pdf rendering? Of the entire set of html produced by document.html() is there any that you can remove manually to get it to work?

Comment: It seems that either your HTML contains cells with bigRowspans or some of the cells are missing, since these are the potential scenarios for such an issue. However, without a proper look at your HTML it's really hard to tell... Perhaps you could share it?